# 'opam install uri' failed

Tags: ocaml, opam

I'm trying to install the uri package for Opam but I keep running in to this error.

```
==== ERROR [while installing uri.1.3.8] ====
# opam-version    0.9.6 (latest-103-g955b7ca)
# os              linux
# command         ocaml setup.ml -configure --prefix /root/.opam/system
# path            /root/.opam/system/build/uri.1.3.8
# exit-code       1
# env-file        /root/.opam/system/build/uri.1.3.8/uri-ffb3fd.env
# stdout-file     /root/.opam/system/build/uri.1.3.8/uri-ffb3fd.out
# stderr-file     /root/.opam/system/build/uri.1.3.8/uri-ffb3fd.err
### stderr ###
ocamlfind: Package `compiler-libs.toplevel' not found
W: Field 'pkg_compiler_libs_toplevel' is not set: Command ''/root/.opam/system/bin/ocamlfind' query -format %d compiler-libs.toplevel > '/tmp/oasis-85d951.txt'' terminated with error code 2
E: Cannot find findlib package compiler-libs.toplevel
E: Failure("1 configuration error")

'opam install uri' failed.
```

I'm pretty new to Ocaml and the Opam repo. I really have no idea what is going wrong. I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and have Ocaml 3.12.1 installed.

Thanks for any insight you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just installing `uri` under 3.12.1 without any issues.

3.12.1 is under your system ocaml compiler, right? and you probably installed ocaml via aptitude? In which case you need to also install `ocaml-compiler-libs`. There are a number of other optional packages for OCaml that are usually needed and may run into in the future --`camlp4-extra` is another that I see missed and oft needed. A maximal list is [here](http://packages.debian.org/source/wheezy/ocaml).

I would also upgrade `OPAM`, since there were some changes to the `uri` package only two days ago. `opam update; opam upgrade`. This will require some re-compilation, and make sure you switched to the correct compiler.

Answer (score 2):

The package "compiler-libs.toplevel" is missing. If I remember right, it's shipped together with ocaml and is available only since version 4.0.

Either install an older version of uri or update your compiler to 4.0. For details look [here](http://opam.ocamlpro.com/doc/Advanced_Usage.html)

Comment: If that truly is the case --which I'm not doubting--, then that is an issue with the URI package configuration in opam-repository. They should specify a minimum version of OCaml in it's configuration.

Comment: OPAM package creators are not almighty and their test resources are limited. If you find any misconfiguration of opam files in your environment, please report the issue at https://github.com/OCamlPro/opam/issues .